# Método para saber cuantas veces se repite un numero en dos arrays

Tags: javascript

¿Hay algún método o alguna forma muy corta para saberlo?

Tengo una función que me devuelve los números que están en ambos `arrays`:

```
match([1,2,2,1], [2,2]); // devuelve [2]
match([4,9,8,5,0], [1,6,4,9]); // devuelve [4,9]
match([3,3,2,1,0], [2,2,3,3,1,7]) // devuelve [1,2,3]
```

Pero quiero hacer que devuelve exactamente la cantidad de veces que estén repetidos en ambos `array`:

```
matchMejorado([1,2,2,1], [2,2]); // devolvería [2,2]
matchMejorado([4,9,8,5,0], [1,6,4,9]); // devolvería [4,9]
matchMejorado([3,3,2,1,0], [2,2,3,3,1,7]) // devolvería [1,2,3,3]
```

En el último ejemplo no devuelve `2` dos veces, **porque no se repite dos veces en ambos array**

He intentado haciendo dos bucles, uno por cada array, inicializando un contador que cuente cuantas veces se repite cada número, pero sólo me sirve para el primer ejemplo ([2,2])

Comment: Te falta lo más importante: lo que has intentado

Comment: Hecho, perdón es que perdí el código con los bucles que había intentado.

Comment: Es que no es lo mismo partir de cero que de un código que no funciona (además de no ayudarte a entender el por qué no funcionaba para que no cometas el mismo error en el futuro).

Answer (score 2):

Yo recorrería cada elemento de la primera matriz en busca de coincidencia en la segunda y cuando exista coincidencia lo eliminaría para que no vuelva a encontrarse el mismo elemento en siguientes búsquedas:

```js
let matchMejorado = (matriz1, matriz2) => {
  /* Inicialmente no existen elementos coincidentes */
  let resultado = [];
  /* Buscamos uno a uno los elementos de la primera matriz en la segunda */
  matriz1.forEach((elemento) => {
    /* Buscamos la posición del elemento en la segunda matriz */
    let posicion = matriz2.indexOf(elemento);
    /* Si no devuelve -1 es porque encontró el elemento */
    if (posicion != -1) {
      /* Agregamos el elemento al resultado */
      resultado.push(elemento);
      /* Eliminamos el elemento de la segunda matriz para no repetirlo */
      matriz2.splice(posicion, 1);
    }
  });
  /* Devolvemos la matriz que contiene los elementos coincidentes */
  return resultado;
}

// devolvería [2,2]
console.log(matchMejorado([1,2,2,1], [2,2]));
// devolvería [4,9]
console.log(matchMejorado([4,9,8,5,0], [1,6,4,9]));
// devolvería [1,2,3,3]
console.log(matchMejorado([3,3,2,1,0], [2,2,3,3,1,7]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Para hacer lo que propones, podríamos mirarlo de otra forma, repensando los requisitos podemos concluir que:

- `matchMejorado(a1, a2)`: debe devolver todos los valores de a1 que se repitan en a2.
- `match(a1, a2)`: debe devolver todos los valores **únicos** de a1 que se repitan en a2. (si te interesa conservar match())

Para esto te propongo lo siguiente, aunque puede parecer enrevesado.

La función `match`, al devolver un subset de la función `matchMejorado` puede consumir a esta aplicándole un objeto `Set` (objeto de valores únicos).

La función `matchMejorado` debe recorrer el array1 (o el 2, es irrelevante) y asignar valores a un nuevo `Array` atendiendo a las siguientes condiciones:

- Que el elemento de `arr1` esté contenido en `arr2`
- Que la cantidad de elementos iguales al elemento evaluado en el `resultArray` sea inferior a la de `arr1`
- Que la cantidad de elementos iguales al elemento evaluado en el `resultArray` sea inferior a la de `arr2`

De esta forma obtendrás el resultado que necesitas.

Te dejo un ejemplo.

```js
const matchMejorado = (arr1, arr2) => {
  let result = [];
  
  arr1.forEach(el => {
    if(
      arr2.includes(el)
      && (result.filter(item => item === el).length < arr1.filter(item => item === el).length)
      && (result.filter(item => item === el).length < arr2.filter(item => item === el).length)
    ){
      result.push(el);
    }
  });
  return result.sort()
};

const match = (arr1, arr2) => [...new Set(matchMejorado(arr1, arr2))];


console.log(
  match([1,2,2,1], [2,2])
); // devuelve [2]
console.log(
  match([4,9,8,5,0], [1,6,4,9])
); // devuelve [4,9]
console.log(
  match([3,3,2,1,0], [2,2,3,3,1,7])
); // devuelve [1,2,3]

console.log(
  matchMejorado([1,2,2,2,1], [2,2])
); // devolvería [2,2]
console.log(
  matchMejorado([4,9,8,5,0], [1,6,4,9])
); // devolvería [4,9]
console.log(
  matchMejorado([3,3,2,1,0], [2,2,3,3,1,7])
);// devolvería [1,2,3,3]
```